# How to call two functions, one after another, using the same button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's what I am trying to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#div1").remove();
    }); // Missing function end
 });

$("#div1").("<b>Appended text</b>");
});
```

HTML

```
 <div id="div1" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:gray;"> 
    <p>This is a paragraph in the div.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph in the div.</p>

 </div> 
    <button id="btn1">Remove div element</button>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: What did you try? where are you having trouble?

Comment: `<br>` in javascript code...... check your browser console

Comment: Why do you have linebreaks in your javascript?

Comment: i am trying to remove "div1" child element and append another element using button click

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
 $("#div1").html("<b>Appended text</b>");});});` , just use `html()` this will replace exhisting content with new html code

Comment: i am new in stackoverflow so i add <br> tag to move code in new line.

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please mark the best answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions are called in the order you put them in the code within an event handler so you can do this to call `.empty()` before calling `.append()` to add new text and you can even chain the two commands one after the other so you don't have to reevaluate the selector:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#div1").empty().append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Or, you could just assign the HTML and skip the `.remove()` which will replace all the HTML in that element like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#div1").html("<b>Appended text</b>");
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note:** `.remove()` removes the containing element and all its contents which it doesn't look like is what you want to do.  If you just want to clear the element contents, you can use `.empty()`.  But, in this case, it is simpler to just assign new contents which replaces the previous contents using `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is instead of removing the existing element just over-write the contents.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("button").click(function() {
       $("#div1").html("<b>Appended text</b>");
    });
});
```

or you can create an element of that id on the fly with some text/html and append it to the body.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("button").click(function() {
       $("#div1").remove();
       $('<div>',{
           html:"<b>Appended text</b>", //<------here update the content.
           "id":"div1"
       }).appendTo(document.body);
    });
});
```